# accessing a singleton as a concatenated variable

Tags: php

How can I get something like this to work

```
$name = 'Config';
$static = $name . '::init()';

$static->test();
```

how can I access the test method from that setup?

I want to piece together a couple of variables to build up a dynamic singleton call.

so `$name` could be 'Db', 'Array' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

```
$name = 'Config';
call_user_func(array($name , 'init'));
call_user_func($name.'::init'); // As of 5.2.3
```

Comment: the server i'm sandboxing in runs on 5.2.17, you think that will support it?

Comment: Yes, the first second way need php version >= 5.2.3, not mean excitely the same.